# Stat command detail information

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, stat

I am running command $stat -c%y filename  on linux system
Output:2014-03-08 13:26:29.335545828 -0800

I am not able to understand the last -0800 thing. Anyone have any idea ?

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be your offset from UTC - ie your timezone. Guessing you are on the west coast of the US?

Comment: I am in IST timezone . Is there any command to get this offset?

Comment: Is that mean 13:26:29 is UTC time

Comment: Wed Mar 12 5:21:37 PDT 2014

Comment: So my answer to your original question was correct - the -0800 is the timezone. If you want your date command to work in IST, you will need to change the timezone of your system (google provides many ways to do this).